# .net core 6: execute middleware on a route

Tags: c#, routes, middleware, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using .net core 6 and from the below image, I saw that the middlewares are executed before routing:
[image]

But you have the possibility to execute a middleware for a certain route, like in this extension method:

```
        public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapMyHealthChecks(
            this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints,
            string pattern = "/myhealth")        
        {

            var pipeline = endpoints
                            .CreateApplicationBuilder()
                            .UseMiddleware<MyHealthChecksMiddleware>()
                            .Build();

            return endpoints.Map(pattern, pipeline)
                            .WithDisplayName("My custom health checks");

        }
```

So, is this diagram still valid? And in this case, what is the order of execution: routing and then middleware?

Comment: routing also the part of [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)..